# How can i display video duration with ffplay?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffplay

I'm trying to display the video duration using ffplay. I have figured out how to display current frame timestamp but can't get the duration.The only thing that i have done is this:

> ffplay -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts:hms}'" -i video.mp4

which is not what i want. Any idea?